# Connect to Specific Data Store Mongo

Tags: macos, mongodb

How do I connect to a database with the `mongo` interactive shell? I don't want to connect to the default path (`/data/db`).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `mongo` connects to the database that is on the default port and host ([source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/#connect-to-a-mongod)):

> By default, mongo looks for a database server listening on port 27017
>   on the localhost interface.

So you should first run the `mongod` daemon (service) with your desired db location:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/some/path/to/desired/db/directory
```

Now that the daemon is running, run `mongo` to connect to it:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2014-09-01T20:24:44.335-0700 ** WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface,
2014-09-01T20:24:44.335-0700 **          enabling http interface
2014-09-01T20:24:44.348-0700 [initandlisten] 
2014-09-01T20:24:44.348-0700 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
>
```

Type `show dbs` to view all databases available in your datastore:

```
> show dbs
admin  (empty)
feeds  0.078GB
local  0.078GB
test   (empty)
>
```

And `use <db name>` to switch to using one:

```
> use local
switched to db local
>
```